# Changable setting after compiling pyinstaller .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, settings

So, I have main.py and settings.py. When I compile main.exe with pyinstaller --onefile, settings.py added to .exe (???) and none of the changes applyes to .exe. So, how can I make  settings?

main.py:

```
from settings import *

pg.display.set_mode(WIN_RES, flags=pg.OPENGL | pg.DOUBLEBUF)

class App: ...
```

setting.py:

```
import pygame as pg

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1600, 900
```